# IOS:Why doesn't Web Speech work with a wireless headset?

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-chrome, safari, webspeech-api

### Background

I encountered an issue while attempting to use the Web Speech API with a wireless headset. The problem is that Web Speech often fails to recognize my voice, resulting in no output and errors. This **inconsistency** in Web Speech's performance is also a problem, and I'm seeking a solution.

### Test Results

To diagnose the problem, I conducted tests to determine which wireless headsets work best with an iPhone. I observed the following results:

Apple wireless headsets, such as Beats and Airpods, exhibited good compatibility with Web Speech, but their performance was **inconsistent**.

In contrast, other wireless headsets, like those from Sony and Yamaha, appeared to perform **worse** than Apple's wireless options.

##### Behavior with Wireless Headsets

When using wireless headsets, I tested Web Speech on various devices and browsers to evaluate its behavior.

**iOS Chrome**: It did not work as the same as each device's behavior. Occasionally, it worked over all tested devices.

**Safari**: Web Speech consistently **failed** to function across all devices.

**Windows PC and Android Chrome**: Web Speech consistently worked well with the wireless headsets I tested.

##### Behavior Without Wireless Headsets

When using devices without wireless headsets, I observed that Web Speech consistently worked across all tested platforms, including iOS Chrome, Safari, Windows PC, and Android Chrome.

### Tech stack

- [React.js](https://react.dev/)
- [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) wrapped by [react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition)
- [Official Web Speech API Demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)

### Live demo and sample code

[sample with web speech](https://vc45fl.csb.app/)

### Desired Outcome

I'm seeking a solution to make Web Speech work consistently with all wireless headsets. Your insights and guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.